# Is the 4x5 chessboard complex a link complement?

Tags: knot-theory, chess, simplicial-stuff, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

The 2x3 and 3x4 chessboard complexes (form a square grid of vertices and make a simplex for any set of vertices no two of which are in the same row or column) are a 6-cycle and a triangulated torus with 24 triangles, respectively. The 4x5 chessboard complex is only a pseudomanifold — each vertex has the 3x4 torus as its link, rather than a spherical link that a proper manifold would have — but if you delete its 20 vertices you get a bona-fide cusped hyperbolic 3-manifold, triangulated by 120 regular ideal tetrahedra. It sort of looks like the kind of manifold you might get as the complement of a 20-component link in Euclidean space. Is it a link complement? And if so, which link is it the complement of?

Edit: here are a couple of general references on chessboard complexes.

Ziegler, G. M. (1994). Shellability of chessboard complexes. [Israel J. Math. 87: 97–110](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02772986).

Björner, A.; Lovász, L.; Vrecica, S. T.; Zivaljevic, R. T. (1994). Chessboard complexes and matching complexes. [J. London Math. Soc. 49: 25–39](http://web.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/morepapers/chess.pdf).

They also have important applications to the proof of colored Tverberg theorems in discrete geometry: see, e.g.

Pavle V. M. Blagojević, Benjamin Matschke, Günter M. Ziegler (2009). Optimal bounds for the colored Tverberg problem. [arXiv:0910.4987](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4987).

Comment: @David, can you provide some reference(s) for chessboard complexes?

Comment: Can you provide the triangulation?  If you have the triangulation handy you can readily write a script (I have one here, if you like) for the python interface to SnapPea, to look for your manifold in the census of link complements.  I could e-mail you the script or you could send me the triangulation, whichever you like. 

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be a link complement - the cusps are rather large, but the systoles of the cusps aren't large enough to rule out outright. You probably won't find this in any census, since the volume is so big. The first thing to check would be the homology. Unfortunately, although there is an algorithm to check if a cusped manifold is a link complement, it's not very practical to implement. There are finitely curves to check on each cusp, so that any link complement must have one of these curves as a meridian. Then you Dehn fill each possible meridian, regeometrize, and induct. 

Comment: Ah, 120 *regular* ideal tetrahedra.  Do you know the symmetry group of the triangulation -- could this be something as simple as a 120-sheet cover of the Gieseking manifold? 

Comment: The symmetry group should be just the permutations of the rows and columns of the 4x5 grid, S4 x S5.

Comment: If anyone discovers which links this is the complement of, I'd love to find out. 

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I met this manifold before. It is a normal cover of the orbifold $\mathbb{H}^3/\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}[\zeta])$ where $\zeta=e^{\pi i/3}$.

I suspect that it actually is $\mathbb{H}^3/\ker\left(\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}[\zeta])\rightarrow \mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]/I)\right)$ where $I$ is the ideal $\langle 2+2\zeta\rangle$.

For $I=\langle 2+\zeta\rangle$, the manifold is a link complement, see Ian Agol's paper on the Thurston Congruence Link for a drawing.

For $I=\langle 3\rangle$, I could show that it is a link complement, but failed at constructing the link.

Comment: Here is the file for the manifold for SnapPea/SnapPy:

http://math.berkeley.edu/~matthias/normal_cover_of_bianchi_orbifold_with_120_reg_tets.trig

According to SnapPea/SnapPy, the homology is Z^20, so it might be a link complement.

Comment: Ah.  And the symmetry group is apparently octahedral x $\Sigma_5$. 

Comment: I just plugged this into SnapPea, and did 1/0 surgery on each component, and it gave the trivial group. So Matthias' manifold is a link complement.

Comment: This is the manifold from my question, right? Not the one with I = <3>.

Comment: @ David: Yes, your manifold appears to be a link complement. However, it might be quite a pain to find an explicit link diagram. It also seems to have many distinct embeddings into S^3.

Comment: @ David: Yes. I double checked this morning:

1. My manifold has 120 regular tetrahedra, 20 cusps, and each cusp has 24 triangles such that they form a regular map {3,6} of the torus. The cusp looks like the lattice $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ divided by $I=\langle 2+2\zeta\rangle$. It is a normal cover of the Bianchi orbifold for $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. It covers it 720 times. By construction (through my Python script), it is the largest normal cover of this Bianchi orbifold with this fixed cusp structure.

Comment: Sorry, I was over the character limit.

2. The order of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]/\langle 2+2\zeta\rangle)$ is twice that of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]/\langle 2+2\zeta\rangle)$ which is the product of $\mathrm{SL}$ for $2$ and $1+\zeta$. We get $60*24/2=720$. So my manifold really is the one for $I=\langle 2+2\zeta$.


Remark: For large enough ideals $I$, the largest normal cover with fixed cusp structure seems to be larger than the manifold with symmetry group $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]/I)$.

Comment: 3. By construction, the symmetry group of your manifold acts transitively on the tetrahedra, even the oriented flags. The triangulation of a cusp cross section has the same property. Furthermore there are 6 triangles meetings at a vertex in a cusp cross section. Regular maps of the torus of type {3,6} are classified by ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. Because you have 24 triangles, the norm needs to be 12. The only ideal (up to conjugacy) is $\langle 2+2\zeta\rangle$.

Comment: Yesterday I tried the same fillings as Ian: when I saw that the fundamental group had no generators and no relators, I interpreted it as "SnapPea cannot find a presentation because it's too complicate". :-D

Answer (score 16):

Figure 1.27 of 
http://math.berkeley.edu/~matthias/research/matthias_goerner_thesis_print.pdf
shows the link.

[image: Figure 1.27]

Comment: Nice image! And thanks for the cite back to this question.